# Touchpad and keyboard mostly don't work on Asus Q534UXK running Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, asus, 20.10

I just installed Ubuntu 20.10 on my Asus Q534UXK laptop, and I'm having a lot of input device problems. On the built-in keyboard, none of the keys seem to do anything, except for the keyboard shortcuts for screen brightness (Fn-F5 and Fn-F6), which work just fine. The touchpad doesn't work at all.

The touchscreen seems to be emulating a mouse, because in Firefox, swiping up and down on the screen selects text instead of scrolling. That might be an unrelated issue.

I plugged in an external keyboard and it works just fine. Furthermore, if I use Ctrl-Alt-F3 to switch to the Linux console, then the built-in keyboard works just fine. (I also see some kind of nouveau MMIO fault message printed to the console, but I'm guessing that's also unrelated.)

(Side note: composing this question *on* the affected device was a somewhat interesting experience.)

Here's the output from `xinput`:

```
tanner@achilles:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Generic USB Keyboard Mouse                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M510                             id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M510                             id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:3022 Touchpad            id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:3022 Mouse               id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Generic USB Keyboard                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Generic USB Keyboard Consumer Control     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Generic USB Keyboard Mouse                id=25   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=24   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Generic USB Keyboard System Control       id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=23   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

If I run `xinput --test-xi2 --root`, then pressing keys on the external keyboard gives me events for device 12 ("Generic USB Keyboard"), tapping the touchscreen gives me touch events on device 19 ("Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer"), and using the brightness keyboard shortcuts gives me events on device 8 ("Video Bus"). Pressing any other key on the built-in keyboard, or using the touchpad, does nothing.

If I run `xinput --list-props 22 | grep 'Device Node'` (on device 22, "ELAN1200:00 04F3:3022 Touchpad"), that reveals that its device node is /dev/input/event6. If I then do `sudo cat /dev/input/event6`, then touching the touchpad prints lots of "junk" to the screen. That seems like good news, at least.

Likewise, if I run `xinput --list-props 24 | grep 'Device Node'` (on device 24, "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"), that reveals that its device node is /dev/input/event4. If I then do `sudo cat /dev/input/event4`, then pressing keys on the built-in keyboard prints lots of "junk."

So, apparently input is showing up on the device nodes, but this isn't successfully getting translated into events for some reason. However, the Linux console understands the keyboard just fine.

I tried uninstalling `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` and installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptic` and rebooting, and that didn't seem to change anything. Uninstalling `xserver-xorg-input-synaptic` and installing `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` and rebooting didn't seem to change anything either. (Maybe those were silly things to try, I don't know.)

What should I do next to try to diagnose and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem now seems to have been resolved, but I'm not sure why.

I opened the Software & Updates application and went to the Additional Drivers tab, which listed one device: "NVIDIA Corporation: GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M]." There were six driver options to choose from, and the selected one was "Using X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)." I selected "Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-460 (proprietary, tested)" instead, which caused a "reboot" button to appear, which I clicked.

After the laptop rebooted, the keyboard and touchpad then worked just fine. However, when I opened the Software & Updates application again, I saw that the Nouveau option was selected again, as shown below.

So I'm not sure if changing the NVIDIA driver actually fixed the problem (which seems like it would be weird, since a touchpad is not a graphics card), or the problem resolved itself for unrelated reasons at the same time that I rebooted.

[image: The Additional Drivers screen, with the following option selected: Using X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)]